# using Certificates with API calls

Tags: api, certificates

I've to use certificates in one of my future project, so want to be prepared beforehand regarding the process involved and technicalities.

I've gone through following links and based on that have few questions:

[Using certificates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs.htm)

[Using certificates with SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_soap.htm)

[Two way SSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL)

I know there are two kinds of certificates :

> Self signed and CA signed

**First question regarding Self signed Certificates :** 
After generating certificate, do We need just provide that to external service provider(whose web service I'm invoking ?)
I was reading somewhere .PEM file needs to be sent to service provider(SP). but downloaded certificate from salesforce is having extention .CRT.

- 1.Do we need to convert that .CRT to .PEM file before sending ?
- 2.How that conversion is done ?
- 3.just to confirm, any thing else need to be provide besides that .PEM/.CRT file?

**Second question regarding CA signed Cerficates** 
How actually this works ? After using 'CreateCA signed Certificate' button, I saw we can download 'Certificate Signing Request' from salesforce(another button is there), which is kind of file with .CSR extention.

- How we send this file to CA for signing (Via email or somewhere i've to upload it ? etc )
- Would this be some kind of buying/selling, where they would be charging in lieu of signing that certificate ?

  - will extension of signed certificates be .PEM file ?
  - I noticed, I get 'upload Signed Certificates' button For CA certificates. Why I need to upload in SFDC , why I can't directly send to this to service provider(SP)?
  - Anything else need to be provided besides this? I was reading somewhere, we need to 'also' provide PUBLIC key to SP ? but not sure how I can get this of if this is needed at all.

Any help on all these points will be really appreciated.
thanks !!

Comment: Requesting people to get me answers on this.